# The currency 'HKD' is supported in "DoDirectPayment" method in paypal?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to implement "DoDirectPayment" method in my website.
I have paypal sandbox account and I have paypal api into.
When I have set the currency as 'USD' then my code return success message.
But when I set 'HKD' currency then it return "This transaction cannot be processed due to an unsupported currency" message.

Here I have attached my code. Please check and give me some solution.

```
$api_version = '78.0';
$api_endpoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';

$api_username = 'platfo_1255077030_biz_api1.gmail.com';
$api_password = '1255077037';
$api_signature = 'Abg0gYcQyxQvnf2HDJkKtA-p6pqhA1k-KTYE0Gcy1diujFio4io5Vqjf';



$creditcardtype = 'VISA';
$cardno = '4854897648835021';
$expdate = '112020';
$cvv = '176';
$PRICE = '50.00';
$currency_code = 'HKD';
$request_params = array(
                        'USER' => $api_username, 
                        'PWD' => $api_password, 
                        'SIGNATURE' => $api_signature, 
                        'VERSION' => $api_version, 
                        'PAYMENTACTION' => 'SALE',                   
                        'CREDITCARDTYPE' => $creditcardtype, 
                        'ACCT' => $cardno,                        
                        'EXPDATE' => $expdate,           
                        'CVV2' => $cvv, 
                        'AMT' => $PRICE, 
                        'CURRENCYCODE' => $currency_code, 
                        'FIRSTNAME'=>'James',
                        'LASTNAME'=>'Smith',
                        'STREET'=>'FirstStreet',
                        'CITY'=>'SanJose',
                        'STATE'=>'CA',
                        'COUNTRYCODE'=>'US',
                        'ZIP'=>95131
                   );
$request_params['METHOD'] = 'DoDirectPayment';


$nvp_string = '';
foreach($request_params as $var=>$val)
{
    $nvp_string .= '&'.$var.'='.urlencode($val);    
}

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl);     
curl_close($curl);
$response = NVPToArray($result);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';


function NVPToArray($NVPString)
{
    $proArray = array();
    while(strlen($NVPString))
    {
        $keypos= strpos($NVPString,'=');
        $keyval = substr($NVPString,0,$keypos);
        $valuepos = strpos($NVPString,'&') ? strpos($NVPString,'&'): strlen($NVPString);
        $valval = substr($NVPString,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
        $proArray[$keyval] = urldecode($valval);
        $NVPString = substr($NVPString,$valuepos+1,strlen($NVPString));
    }
    return $proArray;
}
```

Here is the output message 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIQvJ.png

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/?mark=currency , in "Multi-currency support for direct credit card products" part, if your sandbox account country is USD, the supported currencies are AUD, CAD, EUR, GBP, JPY, USD, so HKD is not supported.